# Parsing ksoap2 response into array of int

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I get a response from the web service:

```
GetMonthsResult=anyType{int=1; int=2; int=3; int=4; int=5; int=6; int=7; int=8; int=9; int=10; int=11; int=12; };
```

How can I parse it into an array of int?

Comment: what type of response you are trying with.JSON/XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on [how to work with array of complex objects with KSOAP](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html). It will help you

Comment: In the article, located on your link was a link to the answer.   http://seesharpgears.blogspot.ru/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html